Error: Unresolved reference: applicationId
I am currently working on an SDK, during the setup when I changed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

to
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

in the gradle.build:app file.
I also changed the following
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
}

to
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
}

in build.gradle: project
and
[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

to
[plugins]
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }

I am facing the following error :
Error
I have checked the android block multiple times, even invalidated cache and refreshed and cleaned the project but this error just wont go away. What am I doing wrong ??

I finally figured out what was the issue.
The error occurred after I modified my project to be used as a library instead of an application.
The problem stems from the fact that library modules do not define applicationId like application modules. The applicationId is specific to app modules, and library modules rely on the package name instead.
Just remove the following fields from the defaultConfig block like so
before
after
just remove these fields as they are not defined in the library modules.

Please convert links to images to code blocks.
